# can't find a viable import class for keras.utils.Sequence

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Google Colab. tensorflow version = 2.8.0, and keras is the same.  I am trying to get a `BalancedDataGenerator(Sequence)` class created, but I can't get `keras.utils.Sequence` to load.

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.np_utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.all_utils import Sequence
```

I've tried it taking out "python", or taking out "tensorflow.python", or searching as to where it is now currently located, but haven't found it.

The errors I get are:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from
> 'tensorflow.python.keras.utils'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/**init**.py)
>
> AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'Sequence'
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'keras.utils'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/**init**.py)
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from
> 'keras.utils.all_utils'
> (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/all_utils.py)
>
> ---
>
> NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
> manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

When I go /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils and read all_utils.py I see 'from keras.utils.data_utils import Sequence' as an option and it says that this all_utils.py module is 'used as a shortcut to access all the symbols.  Those symbols werd exposed under **init**, and was causing some hourglass import issue.'

If I read data_utils.py I do see the Sequence module inside there.
if I type from 'keras.utils.data_utils import Sequence' in a cell and run it it looks like it was accepted.  However, if I put that in the balanceddatagenerator.py and import the class I created that uses Sequence, and then import the class I get this error.  I don't know how to overcome this.

How get this installed and imported successfully?

Comment: I just had an error message that indicated that "from imblearn.keras import balanced_batch_generator" was not finding Sequence in keras.utils.Sequence.  And I know that keras.utils.data_utils.Sequence is where it is located.  So, it looks like since I have an updated version of Keras, that they put Sequence in a different place. Why they seem to keep moving Sequence's location, I don't know, but it is causing problems between versions.

Comment: I just found that imblearn also has a tensorflow version of balanced_batch_generator, so switch to tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence and use the imblearn.tensorflow.balanced_batch_generator, and it seems to import without any errors.  Now let's see if I can finally make progress.

Comment: Hi Jennifer. Welcome to our community! It seems that you were having a programming issue. This type of question is off-topic and better asked on Stack Overflow, even though it's in the context of AI. We focus on the **theoretical**, **philosophical** and **social** aspects of AI. See https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: That is funny, @nbro, I was told over there that I should post all my Machine Learning and Data Science questions here in Stackexchange.

Comment: Some people think that our site also covers programming issues, but that's not the case. Programming questions should really be asked on Stack Overflow. There you will find [many programming questions related e.g. to Keras and TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imblearn.keras.balanced_batch_generator` was pointing to an old version of `keras.utils.Sequence` and causing this error.

I just found that imblearn also has a tensorflow version of balanced_batch_generator, so I switched to `tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence`
and the `imblearn.tensorflow.balanced_batch_generator`, and it seems to import without any errors.

Now let's see if I can finally make progress.